# Vue : avoid two data variables synchronization

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a sticky problem with vue app.

In my methods I need to duplicate temporally a data variable:

```
this.El_selected = this.dessign[index].rows[key].element
```

Then, whenever I make a change in "El_selected", the change is also made in "dessign", which is not what I need.

I tried to use an intermediate local variable with the same results.

```
let el_temp = null;
el_temp = this.dessign[index].rows[key].element
this.El_selected = el_temp
```

Even , I tried split in two different methods, but did not succeed.

EDIT (as Creative Learner request. thank you):
The data element:

```
  data() {
return {
  dessign : [],
  eSelected : [0,0],
  elements : [],
  is_selected : false,
  open : false,
  category : null,
  categories_options : [],
  El_selected : null,
  Op_selected : { oscilobatiente : null, mano : null, maneta : null}
};
```

},

The method code:

```
 setId(index,key){
  let el_temp = null;
  this.eSelected = [index,key]
  this.category = this.Op_selected = null

  el_temp = this.dessign[index].rows[key].element
  this.El_selected = el_temp
  this.Op_selected = {
    oscilobatiente : this.El_selected.oscilobatiente,  
    mano : this.El_selected.mano,
    maneta : this.El_selected.maneta
  }
  this.El_selected.oscilobatiente = this.El_selected.oscilobatiente != null ? 1 : 0;
  this.El_selected.mano = this.El_selected.mano != null ? 1 : 0;
  this.El_selected.maneta = this.El_selected.maneta != null ? 1 : 0;
},
```

The last three lines change the value in "dessign". (Checked with VueDevTools)

EDIT 2 ::

the method is called from Button that toggle a sidebar

```
                  <b-button
                    v-b-toggle.sidebar-right
                    variant="default"
                    @click="setId(index,key)"
                  >
                    <feather-icon icon="PlusSquareIcon" size= 24 />
                  </b-button>
```

Comment: No matter you were using a property of an object or a local variable, both are referring to the same object (a HTMLElement?). You've to clone the object, if you want to get two different objects.

Comment: I created this fiddle for you : https://jsfiddle.net/6p7onkyx/ . I am not able to reproduce the issue. Can you please help me in reproducing the issue so that i can help you in resolving.

Comment: Thank you Teemu, both are variables in data,
Thank you  Creative Learner I edited the question

Comment: What is the type `this.dessign[index].rows[key].element`? It seems is an object, if, try it:
`this.El_selected = {...this.dessign[index].rows[key].element}` Or better for nested ones:
`this.El_selected =JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.dessign[index].rows[key].element))`  OR EVEN BETTER: 

`this.El_selected =JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.dessign[index].rows[key])).element`